# Finding Steady States that Meet Additional Constraints

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, markov-chains

I've written a function that returns the steady state given a regular, column-stochastic matrix. I want to use it to solve a larger problem, finding steady states that satisfy certain conditions.

The function seems to work fine on its own. But not as part of the larger problem.

Here's the function definition:

```
SteadyState[M_] := 
 First[Eigenvectors[M]] / Total[First[Eigenvectors[M]]]
```

Used on its own it seems to work well, e.g.:

```
SteadyState[
  {{1/2, 1/2},
   {1/2, 1/2}}
]
```

returns `{1/2, 1/2}` as it should.

But when I try to use it inside of `Solve`, it doesn't behave as expected. For example:

```
Solve[
 SteadyState[
    {{c11, c12},
     {c21, c22}}
    ] == {q1, q2} &&
  q1 >= 0 && q2 >= 0 &&
  q1 + q2 == 1 &&
  c11 >= 0 && c12 >= 0 && c21 >= 0 && c22 >= 0 &&
  c11 + c21 == 1 && 
  c12 + c22 == 1 &&
  c11 == 1/2 && c12 == 1/2 && q1 == 1/2 && q2 == 1/2,
 {q1, q2, c11, c12, c21, c22},
 Reals
 ]
```

Returns the empty set of solutions `{}`, even though I've effectively handed it the solution in the last two constraints!

Could this be because my `SteadyState` function doesn't check that the input is regular and column stochastic? If so, why? And what would be a good way to rectify that?

Comment: I suspect your system is under-determined, since you have 5 equations but 6 unknowns.

Comment: Also, if your problem is larger than 2x2, you might need to do this numerically.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just updated the code to clarify that the problem arises even when the solution is determined. Ditto for `FindInstance`, and `NSolve`.

Comment: This seems overly complicated.  Which variables are known and which do you want to solve for?

Comment: In the end I'm going to need to solve for all of them simultaneous. The end goal is to find a transition matrix (the $c_i$'s) whose steady state (the $q_j$'s) minimizes its own expected error. (To make things even harder, the formula for expected error involves the transition matrix.)

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizes own expected error"?

Comment: `Solve[SteadyState[{{c11, c12}, {1 - c11, 1 - c12}}] == {q1, 1 - q1}, {c11, c12}]` gives an answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris K, that's interesting. But unfortunately it won't generalize to higher dimensions, and it doesn't (yet) explain the cause of the problem. I'll still need to figure out what's going on before I can move on to using this function to solve the larger problem.

Comment: Mike Y: take an identity matrix and interpret the columns as possible outcomes. Then we can represent the accuracy of a probability assignment (another column vector) by taking the squared norm of the difference between these two column vectors. The expected value of those squared norms is one common measure of "expected inaccuracy".

In my case, though, I'll be weighting the columns before summing, with the weights coming from the column-stochastic matrices mentioned in my OP.

(Why? Well, in my field—philosophy—this model has an interesting interpretation...)

Comment: As I read your problem, you are looking for the eigenvector such that the corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda = 1$. But this eigenvector is always $1$, i.e, just a vector of 1's as long as your $M$ is a proper stochastic matrix (pretty sure, working from memory).

Comment: For higher dimensions, you'll need to do this numerically anyhow, not with `Solve`.  I suggest putting reformulating your question to clarify what your true problem is; this is currently a bit vague and hard to answer.

Comment: Chris K: thanks for the suggesting, I'll try reformulating the problem in a bit, when I have a moment. (The whole thing is pretty involved, so I was trying to boil down the bit that's giving me trouble just now. But maybe that's not the best approach.)

Comment: MikeY: no, the eigenvector's elements sum to 1, but they can't all be 1's. (The eigenvector gives the steady state probabilities for the random walk whose transition probabilities are listed in the matrix.)

Comment: Oops, got the eigenvector from the wrong side (left). You are, though, looking for an eigenvector where the eigenvalue corresponds to $\lambda = 1$. So now you are designing the matrix $M$ such that it is stochastic, and that it (or the eigenvector) has some desired properties, correct? Curious to hear what that is.

Comment: Fiddling a bit more, if you specify $M$ and it is properly stochastic, then your vector $q$ is fully determined and you don't need to solve for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have seen right away, for this purpose it's sufficient—and way more sensible—to just put the steady-state condition into `Solve` by hand, as one of the constraints.

To simplify the problem's expression I first defined some helpers:

```
ColumnStochastic[M_] := AllTrue[
   Table[i, {i, Length[M]}],
   Total[M[[All, #]]] == 1 &
   ] && AllTrue[Flatten[M], # >= 0 &]

pvec[v_] := AllTrue[v, # >= 0 &] && Total[v] == 1
```

The following code then runs no problem:

```
A = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}};
q = {q1, q2};

FindInstance[
  A.q == q &&
    ColumnStochastic[A] && pvec[q],
  Join[q, Flatten[A]]
]
```

It finds the solution:

```
{{q1 -> 3/4, q2 -> 1/4, a11 -> 27/32, a12 -> 15/32, a21 -> 5/32, a22 -> 17/32}}
```

Using `Solve` or `Reduce` instead of `FindInstance` also works now to get the general class of solutions.

To find steady-states that meet additional constraints (as alluded in the OP), I can now just `&&` them in alongside the others.